# How to handle SqlException when trying to insert (and row already exists)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a C# MVC app that adds things to a database and that part works.  I have a Primary Key called `CRN`.  When I try to insert a row that contains a CRN that already exists I get `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code` as expected.  However, the program stops there.  I'm trying to figure out how to get a result (something like -1 if it failed or a number of rows added if it succeeded) but continue the program and let me know.  I'm fairly new to this but I'm thinking I need to use `try`  and `catch` maybe (not sure how)?

C#:

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            int result = 0;
            string insertQuery = "Insert Into Classes (OpenClosed, Section, CRN, CreditHours, PartTerm, Capacity, Enrolled, SeatsAvailable, WaitlistCapacity, WaitlistCount, WaitlistAvailability, Days, Campus, Method, Location, Time, StartDate, EndDate, Instructor) VALUES (@OpenClosed, @Section, @CRN, @CreditHours, @PartTerm, @Capacity, @Enrolled, @SeatsAvailable, @WaitlistCapacity, @WaitlistCount, @WaitlistAvailability, @Days, @Campus, @Method, @Location, @Time, @StartDate, @EndDate, @Instructor)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connect);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OpenClosed", selectedClasses.OpenClosed);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Section", selectedClasses.Section);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CRN", selectedClasses.CRN);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CreditHours", selectedClasses.CreditHours);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartTerm", selectedClasses.PartTerm);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Capacity", selectedClasses.Capacity);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Enrolled", selectedClasses.Enrolled);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SeatsAvailable", selectedClasses.SeatsAvailable);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistCapacity", selectedClasses.WaitlistCapacity);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistCount", selectedClasses.WaitlistCount);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistAvailability", selectedClasses.WaitlistAvailability);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Days", selectedClasses.Days);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Campus", selectedClasses.Campus);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Method", selectedClasses.Method);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Location", selectedClasses.Location);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", selectedClasses.Time);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", selectedClasses.StartDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", selectedClasses.EndDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Instructor", selectedClasses.Instructor);
            connect.Open();
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Comment: You can do a SELECT to see if the CRN exists.  If you are doing a lot of INSERTs then the extra SELECT may be to heavy.

Comment: Normally, you'd do a SELECT on the table, to test if the CRN value already exists. Then you'd take appropriate action based on your business processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not** use a try/catch. You shouldn't be using exceptions to handle workflow. You know that the CRN may exist, so this isn't exceptional.

**You should** update your SQL to handle the case that the CRN exists.

There are multiple ways in SQL to check if the CRN exists. If you just want to check and return the number of rows inserted, you could do:

```
Insert Into Classes (OpenClosed
, Section
, CRN
, CreditHours
, PartTerm
, Capacity
, Enrolled
, SeatsAvailable
, WaitlistCapacity
, WaitlistCount
, WaitlistAvailability
, Days
, Campus
, Method
, Location
, Time
, StartDate
, EndDate
, Instructor) 
SELECT @OpenClosed
, @Section
, @CRN
, @CreditHours
, @PartTerm
, @Capacity
, @Enrolled
, @SeatsAvailable
, @WaitlistCapacity
, @WaitlistCount
, @WaitlistAvailability
, @Days
, @Campus
, @Method
, @Location
, @Time
, @StartDate
, @EndDate
, @Instructor
WHERE @CRN NOT IN
(
    SELECT CRN
    FROM Classes
)

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

This returns the number of rows inserted, which could be read directly into an `int` by using ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 0):

try catch is the way to go

```html
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    string insertQuery = "Insert Into Classes (OpenClosed, Section, CRN, CreditHours, PartTerm, Capacity, Enrolled, SeatsAvailable, WaitlistCapacity, WaitlistCount, WaitlistAvailability, Days, Campus, Method, Location, Time, StartDate, EndDate, Instructor) VALUES (@OpenClosed, @Section, @CRN, @CreditHours, @PartTerm, @Capacity, @Enrolled, @SeatsAvailable, @WaitlistCapacity, @WaitlistCount, @WaitlistAvailability, @Days, @Campus, @Method, @Location, @Time, @StartDate, @EndDate, @Instructor)";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connect);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OpenClosed", selectedClasses.OpenClosed);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Section", selectedClasses.Section);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CRN", selectedClasses.CRN);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CreditHours", selectedClasses.CreditHours);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartTerm", selectedClasses.PartTerm);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Capacity", selectedClasses.Capacity);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Enrolled", selectedClasses.Enrolled);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SeatsAvailable", selectedClasses.SeatsAvailable);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistCapacity", selectedClasses.WaitlistCapacity);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistCount", selectedClasses.WaitlistCount);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WaitlistAvailability", selectedClasses.WaitlistAvailability);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Days", selectedClasses.Days);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Campus", selectedClasses.Campus);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Method", selectedClasses.Method);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Location", selectedClasses.Location);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", selectedClasses.Time);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", selectedClasses.StartDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", selectedClasses.EndDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Instructor", selectedClasses.Instructor);
                    connect.Open();
                    result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                { 
                    //TODO your code to handle exception here.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this i guess:

```
string insertQuery = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Classes  WHERE CRN = @CRN) 
Insert Into Classes (OpenClosed, Section, CRN, CreditHours, PartTerm, Capacity, Enrolled, SeatsAvailable, WaitlistCapacity, WaitlistCount, WaitlistAvailability, Days, Campus, Method, Location, Time, StartDate, EndDate, Instructor) VALUES (@OpenClosed, @Section, @CRN, @CreditHours, @PartTerm, @Capacity, @Enrolled, @SeatsAvailable, @WaitlistCapacity, @WaitlistCount, @WaitlistAvailability, @Days, @Campus, @Method, @Location, @Time, @StartDate, @EndDate, @Instructor)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
ELSE SELECT -1 ";
```

this will return -1 if failed else will return the CSN value of the newly inserted column.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a C# guy, but in the documentation for either `Open()` or `ExecuteNonQuery()` it will tell you something like "This function throws exception XXX if it fails`.

Whichever function (or both) is throwing the exception - which you can also deduce from the stack trace - should be wrapped in the try/catch block.

There's a syntax example at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx